# Is the set $ \ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ non-empty?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

$\text{p-adic numbers}:$

**My questions are**-

$(1)$ Is the set $  \ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ non-empty?

$(2)$ Is the set  $ \ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{Q}_p $ non-empty?

$(3)$ If non-empty , then what are the intersection sets ?

I can not conclude the answer.

Please someone help me with details answer or at least hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $q$ is a prime distinct from $p$, then $1/q\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $1/q\notin\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $1/q$ belongs to the set in $(1)$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}_{p}$, the set in $(2)$ is the same as $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Please answer part  $(1)$ or $(2) $ keeping in mind of part $(3)$ question. I asked in part  $(3)$   if $ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z} ) \cap \mathbb{Q} $ or $ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{Q}_p$   are non-empty then which elements belong to it or what would be the sets? Please help me

Comment: Please reply my comment above .  Also in your answer you said that $ \frac{1}{q} $ belongs to the set in $(1)$ if $ q$ is a prime different from $p$. . My question is why only primes, why not any $ \frac{1}{n}$ belong to the set in $(1)$?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR That's a simple proof that the set is not empty. I never said that just elements of the form $1/q$ are there. Actually, the set in (1) is exactly $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I got it after all